# "Craft is unable to determine if an update is available at this time."

Tags: error-message, auto-updates

I am receiving the following error when I click on `Check for Updates` ...

> Craft is unable to determine if an update is available at this time.

Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Technically, this question was a result of a system configuration error for the OP. __But__, Brad's answer is an excellent explanation of why that message would occur, and what should be done when it happens. Since the OP was kind enough to mark Brad's answer as the correct one, we should leave this question open for historical purposes. I've tweaked the original question to be a bit more generic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll get this if (for any reason) your local install can't connect to our web service that holds all of our update and release information.

If this happens, your local install will cache that there was a connection error and cache to not try again for 5 minutes, no matter how many times you refresh.

So you can either wait the 5 minutes and try again, or clear your data caches under Settings->Tools->Clear Caches Tool and try again and hopefully the connection problem will have resolved itself.

You can also check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for any cURL related errors indicating a cURL configuration problem on the box.

Comment: I cleared the cache to no avail. After combing through error logs, I found I had an error with my curl and ssl setup via homebrew. After re-installing those items and reinstalling php55 like so...  `brew install php55 --with-homebrew-curl --with-homebrew-libxslt --with-homebrew-openssl --without-snmp` everything seemed to be fixed and was able to run my updates

Comment: Ahh... well, there is the log files, too. Nice catch. :)

Comment: Please also keep in mind that `php56` [does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595841/installing-mcrypt-extension-for-php-on-osx-mountain-lion).

Comment: @BrianZ Do you remember in which log you found the error? I'm facing a similar issue but not finding anything in craft.log or phperrors.log.

Comment: Great answer. Clearing the data cache worked for me, and now I can buy Brad whiskey.

Comment: downvoted. not a fix.

Comment: @SteveMock Check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for `cURL` related errors.

Comment: negative @BradBell no cURL errors in the logs. Check for updates doesn't work either: "Craft is unable to determine if an update is available at this time." Other Craft installs in the same environment hook up fine. ( Craft CMS 2.6.2952, PHP 5.6.25 )

Comment: beg pardon. "Craft is unable to fetch edition info at this time." when trying to go Pro.

Comment: Can you clear the logs folder, enable devMode, hit the updates page, then zip up the logs folder and send it to support@craftcms.com?

Comment: Done. @BradBell In the meantime: resolved. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I cleared the cache to no avail. After combing through error logs, I found I had an error with my curl and ssl setup via homebrew. After re-installing those items and reinstalling php55 like so...

`brew install php55 --with-homebrew-curl --with-homebrew-libxslt --with-homebrew-openssl --without-snmp`

...everything seemed to be fixed and was able to run my updates.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because my VPN was interfering with local cURL requests. I disabled the VPN and Craft was able to detect updates. I'm working with my VPN provider now to figure out a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `craft/config/license.key` and clean up `craft/storage/runtime`

Answer (score 0):

Check your `craft/config/license.key`

Ours got out of sync with a remote repo and contained unresolved conflict.