# Updates available on local copy but don't show on live site

Tags: manual-updates

My local copy of a live site is showing an update to Craft 2.2 build 2593 is available but a check for updates on the live site gives "Craft is unable to determine if an update is available at this time."

Has anyone come across this kind of behaviour before?

Am I safe to update my local copy, commit changes and push to live site?

Both local and live site are both in sync at the moment running Craft Pro 2.2.2592

Comment: Hi Dave, this looks like it could be a duplicate question, have a read of this to see if it sorts your problem: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/craft-is-unable-to-determine-if-an-update-is-available-at-this-time

Comment: Hi Jamie, yeah I saw that question before I post this one but I'm not sure it answers my question. This is happening on my live site rather than local machine and this has been ongoing problem for several days so don't think it is a cache problem. I've gone through the log file though and it is littered with the following error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) Every time I access an entry or check for an update this error is logged. Maybe this is the cause of the problem? Something is not setup right because this error should not be here.

Comment: Probably better to delete all of your log files, then reproduce the problem, then check the log files again.  Also keep in mind that if Craft can't connect to its web services, then it will cache not to try again fro 5 minutes. So delete your `craft/storage/runtime/cache` folder in between attempts to get accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it’s perfectly safe to update locally and push the changes live.

Two things to keep in mind:

- If there were any migrations in the update, your production site will be put in Maintenance Mode when you deploy the update, and you will need to visit the Control Panel and click the Finish Up button to complete the update. You can tell if this is going to be necessary by checking craft/app/Info.php and seeing if the CRAFT_SCHEMA_VERSION has changed, or by checking to see if there are any new files within craft/app/migrations/.
- If you update locally and then a second update is immediately available, the chances are that you hit a “breakpoint update”, which means that you have to update *TO* a certain release before you can update *PAST* it. That will apply to your production site as well, so in that case, you will actually need to deploy the first update to production, click that Finish Up button if there is one, and then run the second update locally, deploy it, and once again click the Finish Up button.